# Sentence that uses every base64 character

Tags: base64

I am trying to construct a sentence/letter combination that will return every base64 character, but failing to find a word for purposes of unit testing.

The unit tests I have so far are failing to hit the lines that handle the + and / characters. While I can sling a them at the encoder/decoder directly it would be nice to have a human readable source (the base64 equivalent of 'the quick brown dog').

Comment: Hm... The problem I see here is that the sentence will have to be long and so it can be mistyped. And if you don't type it, but copy-paste instead you can use any suitable generated string.

Comment: But if you try to work backwards and incorporate the + and / characters you either get characters with umlaut etc or non-printables which aren't useful for passing in a unittest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a Base64 encoded test string that includes all 64 possible Base64 symbols:

```
char base64_encoded_test[] =
"U28/PHA+VGhpcyA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCB6LCB7LCB8LCB9IHRlc3RzIEJhc2U2NCBlbmNv"
"ZGVyLiBTaG93IG1lOiBALCBBLCBCLCBDLCBELCBFLCBGLCBHLCBILCBJLCBKLCBLLCBMLCBNLCBO"
"LCBPLCBQLCBRLCBSLCBTLCBULCBVLCBWLCBXLCBYLCBZLCBaLCBbLCBcLCBdLCBeLCBfLCBgLCBh"
"LCBiLCBjLCBkLCBlLCBmLCBnLCBoLCBpLCBqLCBrLCBsLCBtLCBuLCBvLCBwLCBxLCByLCBzLg==";

char base64url_encoded_test[] =
"U28_PHA-VGhpcyA0LCA1LCA2LCA3LCA4LCA5LCB6LCB7LCB8LCB9IHRlc3RzIEJhc2U2NCBlbmNv"
"ZGVyLiBTaG93IG1lOiBALCBBLCBCLCBDLCBELCBFLCBGLCBHLCBILCBJLCBKLCBLLCBMLCBNLCBO"
"LCBPLCBQLCBRLCBSLCBTLCBULCBVLCBWLCBXLCBYLCBZLCBaLCBbLCBcLCBdLCBeLCBfLCBgLCBh"
"LCBiLCBjLCBkLCBlLCBmLCBnLCBoLCBpLCBqLCBrLCBsLCBtLCBuLCBvLCBwLCBxLCByLCBzLg==";
```

It decodes to a string composed entirely of relatively human-readable text:

```
char test_string[] = "So?<p>"
    "This 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, z, {, |, } tests Base64 encoder. "
    "Show me: @, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, "
    "N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, [, \\, ], ^, _, `, "
    "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s.";
```

This decoded string contains only letters in the limited range of isprint()'able 7-bit ASCII characters (space through '~').

Since I did it, I would argue that it is possible :-).

Comment: I will have to check this out when I get home at the weekend.

Comment: Suprised the \ doesn't need escaping in your test string.

Comment: oops. Yes, I need to double the backslash to escape it if I want to put this test string in my source code (but not if I read it from a file). Fixed.

Comment: "Since I did it, I would argue that it is possible" Oh please, it wouldn't be stackoverflow if there weren't at least one response stating "you can't/shouldn't do that"

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do that.

`/` in base64 encodes `111111` (6 '1' bits).

As all ASCII (which are the type-able and printable characters) are in the range of 0-127 (i.e. `00000000` and `01111111`), the only ASCII character that could be encoded using '/' is the ASCII character with the code 127, which is the non-printable `DEL` character.

If you allow values higher than 127, you could have a printable but non-typeable string.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to encode/decode, this is the one place where I break the rule of unit testing a single method at once.  You can have methods for encoding or decoding separately, but the only way to tell if you're doing it correctly is to use both encoding and decoding in a single assert.  I would use the following psuedo code.

```
Generate a random string using Path.GetRandomFilename() this string is cryptographically strong
Pass the string to the encode method
Pass the output of the encode to the decode method
Assert.AreEqual(input from GetRandomFilename, output from Decode)
```

You can loop over this as many times as you want in order to say it's tested. You can also cover some specific cases; however, since encoding (sometimes) differs based on the positioning of the letters, you're better off going with a random string and just calling encode/decode about 50 or so times.

If you find that encoding/decoding fails in accepted scenarios, create unit tests for those and filter out the strings that contain those characters/character combinations. Also, document those failures in XMLDocs comments, code comments, and any documentation your app has.

Comment: I am actually using some long strings from the RFC3548.  Since this is just english text, the range of characters is limited.

Answer (score 1):

What I came up with, may prove not unuseful.  Needs to be entered exactly as is: I include a link to a screenshot showing all the usually invisible characters below, as well as the Base64 data string to which it converts, and a table of the relevant statistics pertinent to each of the 64 characters therein.

---

```
            <HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY><PRE>
            Did 

             THE    

              THE QUICK BROWN FOX   

               jump 

                over    

                 the    

                  lazy  

                   dogs 

                    or  

                     was    

                      he    

                       pushed   

                        ?   

            </PRE><B>hmm.</B></BODY><HTML>






            ÿß®Þ~c*¯/
```

---

This encodes to the Base64 string:

```
            PEhUTUw+PEhFQUQ+PC9IRUFEPjxCT0RZPjxQUkU+DQpEaWQJDQoNCiBUSEUJDQoNCiAgVEhFIFFVSUNLIEJST1dOIEZPWAkNCg0KICAganVtcAkNCg0KICAgIG92ZXIJDQoNCiAgICAgdGhlCQ0KDQogICAgICBsYXp5CQ0KDQogICAgICAgZG9ncwkNCg0KICAgICAgICBvcgkNCg0KICAgICAgICAgd2FzCQ0KDQogICAgICAgICAgaGUJDQoNCiAgICAgICAgICAgcHVzaGVkCQ0KDQogICAgICAgICAgICA/CQ0KDQo8L1BSRT48Qj5obW0uPC9CPjwvQk9EWT48SFRNTD4NCg0KDQoNCg0KDQoNCg//367efmMqry/==
```

which contains

```
            5--/'s
            4--+'s
            3--='s
            14--0's
            3--1's
            3--2's
            2--3's
            4--4's
            3--5's
            2--6's
            2--7's
            4--8's
            6--9's
            5--a's
            27--A's
            2--b's
            5--B's
            5--c's
            4--C's
            4--d's
            14--D's
            2--e's
            10--E's
            2--f's
            8--F's
            36--g's
            6--G's
            5--h's
            2--H's
            5--i's
            30--I's
            5--j's
            6--J's
            8--k's
            12--K's
            2--l's
            3--L's
            2--m's
            4--M's
            3--n's
            14--N's
            13--o's
            2--O's
            3--p's
            9--P's
            2--q's
            24--Q's
            2--r's
            5--R's
            2--s's
            6--S's
            2--t's
            7--T's
            2--u's
            1--U's
            3--v's
            6--V's
            4--w's
            5--W's
            3--x's
            6--X's
            2--y's
            4--Y's
            3--z's
            5--Z's
```